# C++ header file 'wchar.h' not found using g++ (MacOS)

Tags: c++, g++

Disclaimer - I am completely new to C++ and the way this language works regarding compiling / linking. Using MacOS Mojave.

For a school course we are obliged to use the g++ compiler to compile our c++ projects. G++ seems to be successfully installed; g++ -v results in the following output:

```
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0/8.1.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0
Configured with: ../gcc-8.1.0/configure --enable-languages=c++,fortran
Thread model: posix
gcc versie 8.1.0 (GCC)
```

I created my first "hello world" program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I tried to compile this code (using 'g++ file.cpp), the following terminal output prompted:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/8.1.0/bits/postypes.h:40,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/8.1.0/iosfwd:40,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/8.1.0/ios:38,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/8.1.0/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/8.1.0/iostream:39,
                 from ex1.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/c++/8.1.0/cwchar:44:10: fatale fout: wchar.h: No such file or directory
 #include <wchar.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation ended.
```

The whcar.h file is indeed not present in the above folder. After some digging, I found the whcar file in the following folder: `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1`

Unfortunately I am a bit lost and don't really know what I am talking about, consindering everything is really new for me.

It is greatly appreciated if anyone can guide me in the right direction.

Kind regards,

Thijmen.

Comment: can you paste exact command yup are exacting to perform a compilation? For example something like this should do the trick: `g++ prog.cpp -Wall -std=c++17 -o prog`

Comment: I used only 'g++ prog.cpp'. Using your command results in the same error as stated in my original post.

Comment: So looks like installation was not completed successfully. It should work out of the box. Offtopic: you are using Mac so why you do not use clang?

Comment: Do I have to perform any actions before trying to install g++ again? Also, do you have a good source of how to install g++ correctly on Mac? Sorry, I really am new to all of this.

Comment: We are obliged to use the GNU g++ compiler.

Comment: `using namespace std;` can cause unexpected name collisions.  It is better to prefix calls with `std::` rather than import all of std into your source.

Comment: Thank you. However, said error is still present.

Comment: @stark error happens inside include and `using namespace std;` is after that. Anyway issue is missing system header file, so he can't do anything to fix it on source code side. Problem is incomplete or damaged gcc installation.

Comment: @marekR I understand the issues have to do with a corrupt or incomplete installation. Installing GCC came up with some errors most likely related to permission issues. The only way to change this was by disabling SIP. After trying to install GCC again, it came through without any errors. The issue however still persists...

Answer (score 3):

For me, reinstalling Xcode Command Line Tools and g++ solved the same issue:

```
xcode-select --install
brew reinstall gcc
```

The last line is assuming you have installed [homebrew](https://brew.sh).

Answer (score 0):

I just found out the easiest way of this mess is just download the missing header file to your compiler folder. It will fix everything.